# Do all Android phones with a built-in camera use a folder called "DCIM" to store captured images?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-capture

I am developing an app which uses the phone's default camera application to capture an image and then allow the user to perform some basic editing.

I use the following snippet...

```
Intentintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,*<file>*);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

I want the image captured to be saved in a location that is consistent with the stock camera application.  Can I use the DCIM folder and assume all phones will use that location?

Comment: Apparently, DCF stands for design rule for Camera File system.  DCIM defines a directory structure for digital cameras.  So although it is not an android specification, I would assume that most manufacturers will follow this standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that the default Android camera app will save images in the DCIM folder.  If for some reason a phone manufacturer customized Android with a different camera app, the default location could be different.

You could always check for the existance of the DCIM folder first, and if it doesn't exist, have some kind of a "fall back" location that's specific to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend assuming such a thing e.g. Droid Incredible has an internal 8GB storage and I'm not sure how it stores the images inside so check that.