# How to know where on the SD card the images are being stored, DCIM/Camera, DCIM/100MEDIA?

Tags: android, compatibility, save, copying

I have a method in my application which retrieves the last saved image in my `DCIM/Camera` folder and copies it to another location on the SD card. I've just tested it on another phone and found that it defaults saving to `DCIM/100MEDIA`. How am I able to get this path?

**I ended up writing some code which looped through all the folders in the DCIM folder and retrieved the path of the lastModified() folder.**

Comment: here is some interesting context: http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/5930-definitive-androids-folder-structure.html#post239353,  perhaps one has to check date/time of folders and/or ask use for the default location. i'll be watching this thread for a more definitive answer

Comment: @RichardLogwood Thanks, the date/time of folders was an interesting idea. I ended up writing some code to accomplish this checking the last modified folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it is manufacturer dependent. In addition to using methods described in book, it seems also allowing the user to choose/override the default you "discover" would be an important option.

From Pro Android 3: p 579

> **Unfortunately, there is not a method call to tell you which directory might be used underneath the `DCIM` directory for Camera
>   pictures.** There are a couple of methods though to tell you where the
>   top of the SD card is. The first is
>   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and it returns a `File` object
>   for the top-level directory for the SD card.

See the following Google books link for full page text:
http://books.google.com/books?id=RuN0jb4YASwC&pg=PA579&lpg=PA579

- other references:

[Do all Android phones with a built-in camera use a folder called "DCIM" to store captured images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173204/do-all-android-phones-with-a-built-in-camera-use-a-folder-called-dcim-to-store)

http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/5930-definitive-androids-folder-structure.html#post239353

Comment: That's quite interesting! Albeit annoying that the folder can be different and there's no concrete way of retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
File picDir;            
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7)
    picDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
else
    picDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Pictures/");
```

Hope this can help. Based on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, see your link : `Pictures/ - All photos (excluding those taken with the camera)`

Comment: Yes, sure. I wan inattentive.