# Saving an image file to the Android camera roll directory directly?

Tags: android, air

Is there a way to save an image to the camera roll directory directly? I was using CameraRoll.addBitmapData() call but that converts the bitmapData to a JPEG and all transparency is lost. And also, the image is being heavily compressed. So I would like to save a PNG with transparency to the camera roll directory.

I'm using Adobe AIR 3.6 and testing on Android 4.latest on a Google Nexus 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm able to save an image to the camera roll successfully! The problem now is the native Android Image Gallery app doesn't recognize any images I put there except if I restart the device. It also has a problem with thumbnails (they show a different image or are simply a black background).

Here's what I found:

- **DCIM** – This folder is for Photos and contains another folder named **Camera** which contains all of the photos and videos taken by the phone’s camera (Created by the OS)
- **Download** – Will be automatically create as needed for downloaded files. [Source](http://www.lgforum.com/how_do_is/android-sd-card-folders)
- **Pictures** - Not sure.

**What doesn't work**
Image Gallery doesn't reflect new images added to the directory until the device is restarted. The thumbnails are also incorrect as I stated above.

I've noticed in the Camera directory there is a .ds_store type of file and another directory for thumbnails. Other directories besides DCIM / Camera do not appear to have this file.

**UPDATE**
I found out that it's a known issue that the camera roll does not refresh! If it is an AIR only problem or not I don't know. But there is an extension to refresh the image gallery after you add the image. http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/refresh-gallery/. I haven't tried it.

Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621514/how-to-know-where-on-the-sd-card-the-images-are-being-stored-dcim-camera-dcim)...